# Using breakpoints in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

In Visual Studio when I use a breakpoint, F10 key moves to next step and
F11 key moves next and step into methods while debugging.

What is the equavalents for these keys in Mac for Xamarin Studio ?

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Studio you can see the keyboard shortcuts if you open Preferences and select Key Bindings.

- Step: ⇧⌘O
- Step Into: ⇧⌘I

Answer (score 1):

The key binding can be update in menu **Visual Studio** > **Preferences** > **Key Bindings**.

**Here is the default key binding:**

[image]